# Removing \xa0 from string in a list

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I have a list with a bunch of words:

```
lista = ['Jeux Olympiques De Rio\xa02016', 'Sahara Ray', 'Michael Phelps', 'Amber Alert']
```

I tried to replace the `'\xa0'`:

```
for element in listor:
    element = element.replace('\xa0',' ')
```

But it didn't work. Also, when I `print` the elements, it prints:

```
print(lista[0])
Jeux Olympiques De Rio 2016
```

Does anyone have an idea on how to solve this?

Comment: Strings are immutable, so you're not changing the string with your second code block there. You'll need to replace the element in the list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the easiest way:

```
lista = [el.replace('\xa0',' ') for el in lista]
```

Comment: This works but, has a downside. It calls `replace` on *all* strings, even those without the unwanted unicode character in them.

Comment: But author don't know in which string exactly will this char.

Answer (score 3):

```
for index, element in enumerate(listor):
    listor[index] = element.replace('\xa0',' ')
```

Now you're replacing the string within the list rather than trying to change the string itself. Previously, you were assigning a new string to the same variable name, which doesn't change the previous string but just changes the string that the "element" variable is pointing to. With this, you'll be actually overwriting the list element with a new string.

Answer (score 3):

Just use a list comprehension to replace the ending if a string contains `'\xa0'`:

```
res = [elem if '\xa0' not in elem else elem.replace('\xa0', '') for elem in lista]
```

Your current approach merely re-assigns a name (`element`) over and over without actually modifying the list `lista`. The list comprehension will create a new list with elements from the original list, i.e:

```
for elem in lista
```

and replace all strings that contain `\xa0` i.e:

```
elem if '\xa0' not in elem else elem.replace('\xa0', '')
```

Comment: If replace finds no occurencies in string, it just returns sting unchanged, so: `res = [elem.replace('\xa0', '') for elem in lista]` would be ok

Comment: @thodnev sure, but using `in` is generally faster than a function call. I wasn't arguing the result, rather, was pointing out the fact that it wasn't necessary.

Comment: depends on how long the string is and how much strings in the list need replacement. Imagine, that you have a long string with `\xa0` near the end: in this case you iterate over the string once to know, that it has required char, and then the second time during replace routine. `str.replace` is fast built-in method, which is internally implemented simillar to `in` membership test, so the only time overhead it brings is dot-qualification