# remove \xa0 while writing csv file

Tags: python

I have below code to write a list items as csv file. But while doing that, I see special character Â is occurring in the output csv file. For testing in the local, I have defined a list with character '\xao' included in the list items and tested various ways to remove that and replace with space. But, I still get the special character in the csv output. Can anyone help?

```
import csv
from flask import make_response
import StringIO

csv_list = [['hfhf\xa0 fsdg','dsf'],['fsdgs fsdfs','fsdfsd'],['dsf\xa0 sf','asfg']]    

def download_csv_summary(csv_list):

si = StringIO.StringIO()
cw = csv.writer(si)
filename = 'Test'
cw.writerows(csv_list)        
output = make_response(si.getvalue())
output.headers['Content-Disposition'] = \
    'attachment; filename={filename}.csv'.format(filename=filename)
output.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/csv'
return output
```

Comment: What are you using to open the file, where you see the special character? Could you show what you’ve tried to remove it? Note that U+00A0 is a no-break space, so it’s already whitespace.

Comment: I am writing list and downloading as csv file. In csv file, I see special character. But, actually there is no special character. I found that \xa0 is coming instead of space. For testing, I have created a list including \xa0
csv_list = [['hfhf\xa0 fsdg','dsf'],['fsdgs fsdfs','fsdfsd'],['dsf\xa0 sf','asfg']]

Comment: What I’m saying is, in the example you give, the `\xa0`—which is [a Unicode character called a ‘NO-BREAK SPACE’](https://codepoints.net/U+00A0)—is in the input and isn’t treated specially, so it’s printed in the output as well. Most applications shouldn’t be affected: they’ll show a normal space character, as they should. It may be that whatever you’re using to open the CSV file you download doesn’t understand UTF-8.

Comment: okay..can I replace \xa0 with simple space? is there any way while writing to csv

Comment: You can change it when calling `cw.writerows` like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38830660/8492116).

Comment: Can you let me know how? @Aankhen

Comment: Alright, I’ll write it up as an answer.

Comment: Thanks!! @Aankhen

Answer (score 0):

The `writerows` line needs to be changed to replace the `\xa0`s:

```
import csv
from flask import make_response
import StringIO

csv_list = [
    ['hfhf\xa0 fsdg','dsf'],
    ['fsdgs fsdfs','fsdfsd'],
    ['dsf\xa0 sf','asfg']
]

def download_csv_summary(csv_list):
    si = StringIO.StringIO()
    cw = csv.writer(si)
    filename = 'Test'

    cw.writerows([[str(x).replace('\xa0', '') for x in l] for l in csv_list])

    output = make_response(si.getvalue())
    output.headers['Content-Disposition'] = \
        'attachment; filename={filename}.csv'.format(filename=filename)
    output.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/csv'
    return output
```

Comment: Thanks!! I will try this

Comment: "AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'replace'\n"
I get this error . what if integer also there in the list?

Comment: You can pass them through `str` first. Updated.

Comment: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 925: invalid continuation byte: UnicodeDecodeError
I get this error now

Comment: It sounds like you have an issue in your CSV data.

Comment: I am creating CSV data using the python list. How can I identify issue in data?

Comment: What I mean is, your input has something in it that isn’t being decoded as UTF-8. On which line are you seeing the error?

Comment: That’s what you’re doing right now, but there’s a character in the input that isn’t valid input. According to the error it’s at position 925 in the text. Could you edit the question to include the line at that position?

Comment: File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 925: invalid continuation byte


I am not able to find out where the error coming. Because, it came outside the method successfully. But, while downloading it gives error

Comment: That’s the line of code. I’m asking about the data, which in your question is `[['hfhf\xa0 fsdg','dsf'],['fsdgs fsdfs','fsdfsd'],['dsf\xa0 sf','asfg']]`. Can you try your data in small bits to see where exactly the error happens? For example, just the first record, then just the second record, etc.

Comment: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 380: invalid continuation byte
Yes it is due to the issue in input itself. The original data is taken using sql query from a database. In the SQL output, \xao is not visible and in list, it shows like [[test,Infrastructure - Block Store]]. But only in csv, it is ersulting with special character. Like this - Infrastructure\xa0- Block Store

Comment: Really sorry, but I can’t see anything in what you’ve shown so far that should be causing this error.

Comment: Let me put like this. You query a table and write the content as list which needs  to be written as csv file and get it downloaded. The list looks like below.
list = [[test,Infrastructure - Block Store]]
But actually, record contains \xa0 but not visible in list. Content is like below.
Infrastructure\xa0- Block Store
While writing as csv, it gives a special character included. The issue is due to the input data. Can we identify if any \xa0 like this and replace with space while writing as csv

Comment: Yup, I’ve understood your requirements and the code I’ve given does that, but I don’t know what it is in your input that’s causing the error when you print it. All I can tell you is that the `\xa0` is not the problem; that’s valid UTF-8. You have non–UTF-8 data somewhere else in your input.

Comment: Thanks @aankhen. I found out other way to modify the input data itself.

Comment: That’s great! Maybe you could write it up as answer to your own question and accept it, for anyone who stumbles upon this in the future?

Comment: REGEXP_REPLACE(ProductName, r'([\xa0])', ' ') - I have replaced the special charcter simply in the SQL query while querying the table instead of handling that 
 specially using python

Comment: Ah, okay. It’s weird that `\xa0` specifically would cause problems, but I’m glad you found a solution.